Swift/Golang API: Issue fetching from DB upon view populating
I'm currently facing a bug where the initial like counts for these quotes are defaulting to 0, and only updating to their proper ones when I press the like button. Evidently, my likeQuoteAction method is working properly, and I'm assuming the getLikeCountForQuote method is working because its response from my API has a 200 status code:

Source code for this GET request:
    // GET /quoteLikes/:id - get the number of likes for a specific quote by ID
    r.GET("/quoteLikes/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {
        idStr := c.Param("id")
        id, err := strconv.Atoi(idStr)
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Invalid quote ID."})
            return
        }

        var likes int
        err = db.QueryRow("SELECT likes FROM quotes WHERE id = $1", id).Scan(&likes)
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Quote not found."})
            return
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"message": "Failed to retrieve likes count from the database."})
            return
        }

        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"id": id, "likes": likes})
    })

This is the struct I'm using to populate quotes with their text, author, and likes. This is where I need to change something, such that the initial like counts will be accurate:
struct SingleQuoteView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedVars: SharedVarsBetweenTabs
    let quote: Quote
    @AppStorage("likedQuotes", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.selectedSettings"))
    private var likedQuotesData: Data = Data()
    
    @AppStorage("bookmarkedQuotes", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.selectedSettings"))
    private var bookmarkedQuotesData: Data = Data()
    
    @State private var isLiked: Bool = false
    @State private var isBookmarked: Bool = false
    @State private var likes: Int = 0 // Assuming this is what it's grabbing for the value, without updating until the like button is pressed
    @State private var isLiking: Bool = false
    
    init(quote: Quote) {
        self.quote = quote
        self._isBookmarked = State(initialValue: isQuoteBookmarked(quote))
        self._isLiked = State(initialValue: isQuoteLiked(quote))
    }
    private func getQuoteLikeCountMethod(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        getLikeCountForQuote(quoteGiven: quote) { likeCount in
            completion(likeCount)
        }
    }
    
    private func getLikeCountForQuote(quoteGiven: Quote, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "omitted for stackoverflow") else {
            completion(0)
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data,
               let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
               let likeCount = json["likeCount"] as? Int {
                completion(likeCount)
            } else {
                completion(0)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("\"\(quote.text)\"")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .foregroundColor(colorPalettes[safe: sharedVars.colorPaletteIndex]?[1] ?? .white)
                    .padding(.bottom, 2)
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            if let author = quote.author, author != "Unknown Author", !author.isEmpty, author != "NULL", author != "" {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("— \(author)")
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(colorPalettes[safe: sharedVars.colorPaletteIndex]?[2] ?? .white)
                        .padding(.bottom, 5)
                        .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        likeQuoteAction()
                        toggleLike()
                    }) {
                        Image(uiImage: resizeImage(UIImage(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 75, height: 27))!)
                            .foregroundColor(isLiked ? .yellow : .gray)
                    }
                    
                    // Display the like count next to the heart button
                    Text("\(likes)")
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    toggleBookmark()
                }) {
                    Image(uiImage: resizeImage(UIImage(systemName: isBookmarked ? "bookmark.fill" : "bookmark")!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 75, height: 27))!)
                        .foregroundColor(isBookmarked ? .yellow : .gray)
                }
                
                if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    let authorForSharing = (quote.author != "Unknown Author" && quote.author != "NULL" && quote.author != "" && quote.author != nil) ? quote.author : ""
                    let wholeAuthorText = (authorForSharing != "") ? "\n— \(authorForSharing ?? "Unknown Author")" : ""
                    
                    ShareLink(item: URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/quote-droplet/id6455084603")!, message: Text("From the Quote Droplet app:\n\n\"\(quote.text)\"\(wholeAuthorText)")) {
                        Image(uiImage: resizeImage(UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 75, height: 27))!)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(ColorPaletteView(colors: [colorPalettes[safe: sharedVars.colorPaletteIndex]?[0] ?? Color.clear]))
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .shadow(radius: 5)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .onAppear {
            isBookmarked = isQuoteBookmarked(quote)

            getQuoteLikeCountMethod { fetchedLikeCount in
                likes = fetchedLikeCount
            }
            isLiked = isQuoteLiked(quote)
        }
    }
    
    private func toggleBookmark() {
        isBookmarked.toggle()
        
        var bookmarkedQuotes = getBookmarkedQuotes()
        if isBookmarked {
            bookmarkedQuotes.append(quote)
        } else {
            bookmarkedQuotes.removeAll { $0.id == quote.id }
        }
        saveBookmarkedQuotes(bookmarkedQuotes)
    }
    
    private func toggleLike() {
        isLiked.toggle()
        
        var likedQuotes = getLikedQuotes()
        if isLiked {
            likedQuotes.append(quote)
        } else {
            likedQuotes.removeAll { $0.id == quote.id }
        }
        saveLikedQuotes(likedQuotes)
    }
    
    private func likeQuoteAction() {
        guard !isLiking else { return }
        isLiking = true
        
        // Check if the quote is already liked
        let isAlreadyLiked = isQuoteLiked(quote)
        
        // Call the like/unlike API based on the current like status
        if isAlreadyLiked {
            unlikeQuote(quoteID: quote.id) { updatedQuote, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let updatedQuote = updatedQuote {
                        // Update likes count
                        self.likes = updatedQuote.likes ?? 0
                    }
                    self.isLiking = false
                }
            }
        } else {
            likeQuote(quoteID: quote.id) { updatedQuote, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let updatedQuote = updatedQuote {
                        // Update likes count
                        self.likes = updatedQuote.likes ?? 0
                    }
                    self.isLiking = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func isQuoteLiked(_ quote: Quote) -> Bool {
        return getLikedQuotes().contains(where: { $0.id == quote.id })
    }
    
    private func getLikedQuotes() -> [Quote] {
        if let quotes = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: likedQuotesData) {
            return quotes
        }
        return []
    }
    
    private func saveLikedQuotes(_ quotes: [Quote]) {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(quotes) {
            likedQuotesData = data
        }
    }
    
    private func isQuoteBookmarked(_ quote: Quote) -> Bool {
        return getBookmarkedQuotes().contains(where: { $0.id == quote.id })
    }
    
    private func getBookmarkedQuotes() -> [Quote] {
        if let quotes = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: bookmarkedQuotesData) {
            return quotes
        }
        return []
    }
    
    private func saveBookmarkedQuotes(_ quotes: [Quote]) {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(quotes) {
            bookmarkedQuotesData = data
        }
    }
}

For context, each of these SingleQuoteViews correspond to one of these quotes in my app:

Please let me know if further clarification is needed.

There are too many missing parts to be able to compile and run a test of your code.
It seems you have two ways of getting the likes, one in .onAppear using
getQuoteLikeCountMethod which is just a useless wrapper around getLikeCountForQuote,
and another in the Button(action: { likeQuoteAction() ... which I guess is different.
You could try adding some print("--> likes: \(likes)"), in .onAppear and
other places to see if you get what you expect for likes. Then show us what you get.

Fair comment @workingdogsupportUkraine. Yea, it's a pretty vague question, and especially so considering there's not only this Swift project, but my API it's connecting to. I'm pretty sure the issue just has to do with the Swift part of it, though.
To clarify why there are two likes getters, it's because one is for the user's liked quotes, which are stored in user defaults, just like bookmarked quotes. The other method for getting likes pertains to the like count for a specific quote, which is where the issue is arising from.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Currently what I get from printing the likes from within the .onAppear(), when I initially load the quotes is this (likes values for each of the 4 quotes loaded):
likes 0
likes 0
likes 0
likes 0
Then, after I like a quote, it shows its proper like count (8) in the text box. Though, when I switch TabViews and go back to this TabView, it prints this:
likes 0
likes 0
likes 0
likes 8
Clearly, it's getting the right like count here after having liked it, but weirdly enough, it's actually putting all 0s as the text values for each quote's like count.

I don't see any TabViews in your code, so it is not possible
to say what is going on, specifically how you pass the relevant variables.
In .onAppear, I assume you are printing withing the closure getQuoteLikeCountMethod { ... print(...) } because outside of it you will always get zero.

Before if let data = data, let json = try?... add a print to debug. You need to see what's happening: print("Got for: (url.absoluteString): (response) and stringified data: (String(data: data ?? Date(), encoding: .utf8)")` and see if they are really called and what's the returned values...

@workingdogsupportUkraine I purposely didn't include it to focus on what's relevant to my question. The tabviews simply correspond to the tab buttons you see in the bottom of my iPhone simulator screenshot. There are 0 variables being passed in that affect this bug, since I'm only passing one in that pertains to colors (can see in the code, sharedVars.colorPaletteIndex.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I printed the value at the end of the .onAppear, after the isLiked = isQuoteLiked(quote) line.

func getQuoteLikeCountMethod(...) is asynchronous, so
try printing inside the closure, eg:
getQuoteLikeCountMethod { fetchedLikeCount in              likes = fetchedLikeCount  print("----> likes: \(likes)")          } not after, like you say you do.

Hi @workingdogsupportUkraine, sorry for the late response; I've been busy with my day job. From printing the like counts in the onAppear(), I actually do get the correct values (e.g. 17) when I switch tabviews back to this "Droplets" view. However, when I print inside of the getQuoteLikeCountMethod as you've most recently commented I do, the like counts are always 0, and these are the values displayed next to the like buttons on the screen.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Though, this is only after I click the like buttons then switch away and back to this view. When I initially open the app, both the like counts in getQuoteLikeMethod and at the beginning of the .onAppear() method are always all 0.
@Larme I tried your print statement but got multiple syntax errors, so changing it to the following resolved them:
print("Got for: \(url.absoluteString): \(String(describing: response)) and stringified data: \(String(data: data ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil")")

@Larme I actually did get the right response, as printed out with your print statement (that I modified slightly in my above comment):
Got for: {censored URL for stackoverflow}/quoteLikes/232: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000002c67e0> { URL:{censored URL for stackoverflow}/quoteLikes/232 } { Status Code: 200, Headers {     "likes": 16
However, it unfortunately only displays a like count of 0 using the code I provided in the question. What change do you think I need to make so that it actually properly displays this likes count retrieved from my API?

I have no idea about swift, but, could be you are reading the wrong JSON property? API is returning c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"id": id, "likes": likes})  >> {"id": 123, "likes": 5}. Swift code is trying to read likeCount which doesn't exist let likeCount = json["likeCount"] as? Int , so it should be let likeCount = json["likes"] as? Int

@wakumaku Great catch! This is what solved my issue. Could you post this as an answer, so I can award you the bounty?

I have no idea about swift, but, could be you are reading the wrong JSON property?
API is returning:
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"id": id, "likes": likes})
    // {"id": 123, "likes": 5}

Swift code is trying to read likeCount:
let likeCount = json["likeCount"] as? Int

So it should be let likeCount = json["likes"] as? Int

It seems like an API mismatch between client and server.
You are expecting
               let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
               let likeCount = json["likeCount"] as? Int {

in the client but sending
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"id": id, "likes": likes})

from the server - it would be useful to see the whole response above.
To avoid such issues you could use an OpenAPI description of your service, for example using Swift OpenAPI Generator on the client and swag on the server.
